# How can we insert Poisson and Speckle noise in image of particular variance?

Tags: image, matlab, noise

In MATLAB we can add Gaussian noise of particular value of noise variance in images.
How can we insert Poisson and Speckle noise of particular variance value in image?

Answer (score 1):

the image processing toolbox of matlab contains a function called [`imnoise()`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imnoise.html).

```
J = imnoise(I,'speckle',v)
```

adds speckle noise to the image I, n is uniformly distributed random noise with mean 0 and variance v.

`J = imnoise(I,'poisson')` generates Poisson noise from the data and adds that.